# Express statement "not every student in this class will pass the Discrete Mathematics"

Tags: discrete-mathematics, predicate-logic, quantifiers

I have a bit of a problem with this question:

> Express the following statement using predicate function(s),
>   existential or universal quantifier, and/or negation. “not every
>   student in this class will pass the Discrete Mathematics”.

my solution is

> -(∀ (( Student(x) && Class(DM,x)) -> Pass(DM,x)) )

is my negative forAll and my && between Student and Class correct?

Thx for any help :)

Comment: You have forgotten the variable $x$ of the quantifier...

Comment: but other than that (forgetting $x$ after $\forall$) it's correct.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

$(\exists x\in S)(\sim \operatorname{Pass}(x))$

Where $S$ is the set of students and $\operatorname{Pass}(x)$ is "$x$ passes discrete math".

Answer (score 1):

That is a correct interpretation of the question. As always with English sentences, it's not the only thing you can form. For example, we can form:

$$-(\forall x (DM(x)\rightarrow Pass(x))$$